# Hystrix fallback method is not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I'm trying hystrix fallback method.
On localhost:8082, customer-service is running which returns name of the customer.

If the customer-service is down, fallback method should invoke. But it is not happening.

Below is the code snippet.

Please suggest.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@RestController
public class DemoHystrixApplication {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String name() {
        String str = getCustomerName();
        return str;
    }

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getFallbackCustomerName")
    private String getCustomerName() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8082");
        return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }

    private String getFallbackCustomerName() {
        System.out.println("coming inside fallback method");
        return "Resillient Customer";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoHystrixApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the methods i.e. the actual and fallback methods should be public and move these methods to a separate class and annotate it with @Component.

Give a try, hope this helps.

Comment: why separate class?

Comment: @ses It is just a suggestion to separate the @ SpringBootApplication, @ Controller,  and @ Service/@ Component, instead of all the code at one place. Just a coding best practice suggestion, as over the period of time there will lot of code at one place and difficult to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Your @HystrixCommand annotated method should be public.
Not sure about the fallback method but I would set it public as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of AOP.

The Spring container injects aspect-aware bean when injecting a bean.

When the `name()` function is called at the user's request, the method of the aspect-aware bean is called so annotation works.

However, calling `this.getCustomerName()` directly within the `name()` calls `getCustomerName()` on the raw bean before it is wrapped in proxy. It doesn't know aspect. Therefore, annotation does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try stopping and starting the service, if you added the dependency of netflix-hystrix and have dev-tools to pick up changes while executing the service.

Answer (score 0):

Fallback metod should be  called from another bean. The problem is you are calling fallback method from RestController.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this because of HystrixComman is aspect

```
@Bean
@Primary
@Order(value= Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public HystrixCommandAspect hystrixAspect() {
    return new HystrixCommandAspect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@HystrixCommand` annotated method should be public. The fallback method can be private as well.